# How to add animation to the element's css attributes when the class changes with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

*The problem:*

I have a HTML element which has a class `hidden` which sets the css attribute `display: none;`. When I remove the class with the JS the element becomes immediately visible (the original `display` value is restored). What I would like to be able to set the duration of the "showing up" animation, like I could with: `$('.hidden').show(1000)` or `$('.hidden').fadeIn(1500)`. I tried to chain with `.animate()` but it didn't work.

*The limitations*

1. It can't mess with the inline CSS of the element (especially it can't set the `display: block`)
2. It should behave similar to the jQueryUI removeClass: http://jqueryui.com/removeClass/

*The question:*

> *How to make the changes to be animated (have a duration > 0) when I
>   remove(change) the class of the HTML element?*

*The code:*

**CSS:**

```
.hidden{
display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="hidden"> Lorem ipsum </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.hidden').removeClass('hidden')
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/DU2Wg/1/

With your HTML & CSS, you could use this JS :

```
$('.hidden').css({ // Change your CSS directly to
    display: 'inline', // the display you want
    opacity: 0 // 100% transparent
})
.stop() // Recommended because it pauses any previous animation so there is no conflict between two animations simultaneously
.animate({ // Will change your CSS over time
    opacity: 1 // 100% opaque
}, 2000, // in 2 secs
function(){
    var $this = $(this)
    $this.removeClass('hidden'); // Will remove your class (only if you want to use it once)
    alert($this.css('display')); // Will alert "inline", your current display on that element
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.hidden').show(1000,function(){$(this).removeClass('hidden').css('display','');});
```

This will display it using an animation, once the animation is done we remove the class...

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately it set's the ugly inline `style="display:block"` which I can't allow.

Answer (score 0):

You remove the class that you need to fade it thats the mistake

you can try this
  [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vryyF/2/)

HTML

```
<h1 class="hide" style="display:none; ">Display</h1>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
$(".hide").fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: I don't want to use inline CSS styles - I can't and I find them ugly. The solution  I search should be pure JS/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use `$('.hidden').fadeIn(1500)`?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nUdqK/)

Comment: Because it sets the inline style to `display: block` which is wrong in my setup. I'll update the question to let it be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this animation to run in modern browsers, use css transitions!

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
.hidden.fadeIn{
    display: block;
    opacity:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.hidden.fadeIn.do{
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

In JS you can set the classes like this :

```
$('.hidden').addClass('fadeIn');
setTimeout(function(){$('.hidden.fadeIn').addClass('do');},10);
```

Unfortunately, unless you'll have to use `setTimeout`. If you dont, both class changes will be interpreted in the same time and no animation will occur.

**EDIT**

You might be able with less code if you modify the `hidden` class's rule :

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
    opacity:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.hidden.fadeIn{
    display: block;
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Now you have only 1 class to add with JS :

```
function fade(){
    $('.hidden').addClass('fadeIn');
}
setTimeout(fade,10);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Will check that later. CSS transitions look promising.

Answer (score 0):

I think you talking about jquery's delay function:

```
$('.hidden').removeClass('hidden').delay(1000).addClass('hidden')
```